# Ruby 2.3.3: Weird Tempfile.new([name, prefix]) basename converted to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-2.3

Testing an upgrade to Ruby 2.3.3 for our Rails 3.2.22.2 application, and getting a weird situation where we are passing an array as the first argument to `Tempfile.new`, but it's ending up as a hash.

I've patched `tempfile.rb` to output the `basename` argument being passed in.

In an `irb` session (non-Rails), everything is fine:

```
> require 'tempfile'
true
> Tempfile.new(['test', '.csv'])
["home", ".csv"] # output of basename argument for Tempfile.new
 => #<Tempfile:/var/blah/test###.csv>
```

In a `rails console` session:

```
> Tempfile.new(['test', '.csv'])
{"test"=>nil, ".csv"=>nil}
ArgumentError: unexpected prefix: {"test"=>nil, ".csv"=>nil}
from /path/to/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:113:in `make_tmpname'
```

Gotta be a gem or something, but can't figure out for the life of me why this is happening or where or what is changing the behavior.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to debug?

Comment: What is the output of `puts caller` inside your patched tempfile.rb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I think that somewhere in your code you have the `Array#to_hash` method defined.

I had the same issue and for some reason when a method has a default param, in this case `basename=""`, and a double splatted parameter, Ruby calls the `to_hash` function on the first param.

See the following example:

```
class Dummy
  def initialize(val = "", **options)
    puts "val = #{val}"
    # puts "Options: #{options}"
  end
end

class Array
  def to_hash
    puts "to_hash called on #{self}"
  end
end

Dummy.new(["Joe", "Bloe"])
```

This will output

```
to_hash called on ["Joe", "Bloe"]
val = ["Joe", "Bloe"]
```

But when there's no default value for the `val` param, you'll get:

```
val = ["Joe", "Bloe"]
```

Note that the `TempFile#initialize` function signature was changed from Ruby 2.1 to Ruby 2.2.

Here's the diff:

```
-  def initialize(basename, *rest)
+  def initialize(basename="", tmpdir=nil, mode: 0, **options)
```

Notice that `basename` doesn't have a default value anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering!!!! That's a really nice find! Been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: Nice finding, Thank you.
But having/not having default name, both the cases i am still getting the error while running 'ruby 2.3.1p112'

Comment: My issue was not related to default parameter. I was getting an array in basename and that is having issue in getting converted to string to verify prefix. updating that value from array to a string of filename, fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this in my console, and got no error. Try a few things,

1. Make sure you are using ruby 2.3 or higher in your rail app, because I believe that method `make_tmpname` was handled differently before.
2. Make sure the quotes around `.csv` are quotes and not a tilde `.
3. I get your same error with ruby 2.3.1 if I do this `Tempfile.new(['test', /re/])`

I hope this helps, at the end of the day what's causing your error is this method [try_convert](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/try_convert/class) which is returning `nil` for the second argument you pass to `Tempfile.new`

Comment: `\`` is a backtick (or [grave accent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm)). `~` is a [tilde](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/007e/index.htm).

Comment: I knew someone would correct me about that but couldn't remember the name, thanks dude.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The code above is the code in the app no `~` or `\`` and I'm using 2.3.3 to produce the error. When you say you get the same error using a regex, do you mean you are seeing the `[]` args being converted to a hash?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it.

```
class Tempfile 
  def initialize(basename="", tmpdir=nil, mode: 0, **options)
    warn "Tempfile.new doesn't call the given block." if block_given?

    basename = basename.keys if basename.kind_of?(Hash)

    @unlinked = false
    @mode = mode|File::RDWR|File::CREAT|File::EXCL
    ::Dir::Tmpname.create(basename, tmpdir, options) do |tmpname, n, opts|
      opts[:perm] = 0600
      @tmpfile = File.open(tmpname, @mode, opts)
      @opts = opts.freeze
    end
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, Remover.new(@tmpfile))

    super(@tmpfile)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is not working for me and still getting the same error, while running 'ruby 2.3.1p112'

Comment: This didn't fix my error, but helped me find my error.
In my case, basename was being as an array which was not an issue in ruby-2.1.8, but ruby-2.3.1 started giving error for that.
Array being tried to convert to string, to get the prefix and it was becoming nil and giving runtime error 'unexpected prefix'.
Updating the basename parameter sending to Tempfile, to be a filename string fixed my issue.